# Load fragments inside fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I have an app structure in mind:

DashBoard Activity

- HomeFragment

  - AdsFragment
  - GreetingFragment
  - ExperienceFragment

WIth that in mind, I'm trying to load different fragments in `HomeFragment`, which is also a fragment

I've written the following code in HomeFragment's `onCreateView()`

```
val fm : FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
        val container = R.id.greetingFragmentContainer
        val greetingFragment : Fragment? = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentGreeting)
        if (greetingFragment != null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(container, greetingFragment).commit()
        } else {
            Log.e("HomeFragment", "Fragment not found")
        }
```

`fragment_greeting.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentGreeting"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="._fragments.dash.GreetingFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Using that if statement, I found out that the `greetingFragment` value was returning null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try android:name for specifying the fragment class in the <FrameLayout>

Comment: @RahulShukla that did not work. sorry :/

Comment: sorry, I missed too.

Comment: Honestly, aren't you just looking for ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Oh, I have that combination down. Its just that, I wanted some places, where the fragments are static and are programmatically loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your `HomeFragment`

```
lateinit var context: AppCompatActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        this.context = context as AppCompatActivity
    }
```

and call the fragment without `findFragmentbyId` like below:

```
 val fm = context.supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction
            val fragment = GreetingFragment()
            fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: No need for that `lateinit var`, fragments already have a `getActivity()` method.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes we can use that method, but i sometime experienced crash with that so this is the safe way i thought.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to instantiate the fragments. The method you are using doesn't do anything except just declaring a layout, which is not what you want! Use the following approach to do it correctly.

```
<LinearLayout>
 <fragment android:id="@+id/ad" android:name="._fragments.dash.AdFragment" />
<fragment android:id="@+id/greeting" android:name="._fragments.dash.GreetingFragment"/>
<fragment android:id="@+id/experience" android:name="._fragments.dash.ExpFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, the classes specified in android:name refer to dedicated fragments classes extending the Fragment class. You need to specify the each fragment's layout in dedicated layout resource e.g. R.layout.ad_fragment, R.layout.greeting_fragment and R.layout.exp_fragment, which must be inflated inside onCreateView() function of every Class.

Please refer to [Official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating) for more information.

Comment: This is doing it statically but it helps my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Home fragment should contain three framelayouts for loading AdsFragment, Greetings Fragment,Experience Fragment. 
Fragment can be loaded to frame layouts using child fragment manager.

Answer (score 1):

To load different fragment in same view i did this.

```
    private val manager = supportFragmentManager
```

When you have to load each of fragments ( don't think you have to show all of them on same time) you can do this

```
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    val fragment = FragmentOne()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
```

Good practise would be have a general when statment listening different buttons tapu and then instatiante different fragment, because make different buttons would create more copy code.

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    val fragment = when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.ads_menu -> FragmentAds()
        R.id.grets_menu -> FragmentGreeting()
        R.id.exp_menu -> FragmentExperience()
        else ->  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    val transaction= manager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    return true
}
```

Of course there are three fragment class that have their layout and override all methods.
I try this also in profiler and it seems that.

The issue (if we can call like this) about this solution is that on back pressed all history of fragments is loaded, because replace remove and add a new one.

To avoid it, all fragments could be all visible and changing button just change the selected one but of course it complicated the when statment.

```
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("searchFragment"));
ft.add(R.id.main_fragment, yourDetailfragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.commit();
```